# Stop SetVolumeMountPoint from opening file explorer

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, kernel32, vhd

I am using SetVolumeMountPoint to mount a vhd to a drive letter of my choosing. The problem is that when the vhd is mounted file explorer automatically opens at the new drive directory. This is a problem for me as I need my programs to remain on the foreground and sometimes the spawned file explorer becomes part of the foreground.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setvolumemountpointa

Thoughts?

UPDATE:

I programmatically set the noautorun registry key using these two methods before mounting my vhd:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Removing file explorer auto run for the given DriveLetter so that when a vhd is mounted file explorer doesn't open
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="DriveLetter"></param>
        private void RemoveFileExplorerAutoRun(char DriveLetter)
        {
            var KeyPath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer";
            RegistryKey AutoRunKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(KeyPath, true);
            var DriveLetterValue = DriveLetter - 'A';

            if (AutoRunKey != null)
            {
                RemoveFileExplorerAutoRun(AutoRunKey, DriveLetterValue);
            }
            else // create key as it does not exist
            {
                AutoRunKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(KeyPath);
                RemoveFileExplorerAutoRun(AutoRunKey, DriveLetterValue);
            }
        }

        private void RemoveFileExplorerAutoRun(RegistryKey AutoRunKey, int DriveLetterValue)
        {
            if (AutoRunKey != null)
            {
                AutoRunKey.SetValue("NoDriveTypeAutoRun", DriveLetterValue);
                AutoRunKey.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleanest way seem to be to catch `RegisterWindowMessage("QueryCancelAutoPlay")` message by your foreground window and return TRUE from your window procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/autoplay-reg

EDIT:
If foreground window is not your application window, then I would recommend against editing registry, since it is global state, whereas you need just temporary autorun bypass.

Besides windows hook, mentioned in other answer, I would suggest registering your implementation of [IQueryCancelAutoPlay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl/nn-shobjidl-iquerycancelautoplay) interface in [running object table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-irunningobjecttable)

Comment: It looks like I can disable autorun for specific drive letters from the registry which is a better solution for my application since I always mount the vhds on specific drive letters and my application is not designed to be the foreground window, but it spawns other applications that are the foreground window.

Comment: I suggest against registry change, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using Registry.

Please reference "[Using the Registry to Disable AutoRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/autoplay-reg#using-the-registry-to-disable-autorun)" "[How to disable the Autorun functionality in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967715/how-to-disable-the-autorun-functionality-in-windows)"

**Note**

> The NoDriveAutoRun and NoDriveTypeAutoRun values should only be
>   modified by system administrators to change the value for the entire
>   system for testing or administrative purposes. Applications should not
>   modify these values, as there is no way to reliably restore them to
>   their original values.

The third way is based on @Alexander Gutenev have pointed out that register a "QueryCancelAutoPlay" window message and then install a global [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_getmessage) from your application to monitor this message.

**Note**

> You should use global hooks only for debugging purposes; otherwise,
>   you should avoid them. Global hooks hurt system performance and cause
>   conflicts with other applications that implement the same type of
>   global hook.
>
> Hooks tend to slow down the system because they increase the amount of
>   processing the system must perform for each message. You should
>   install a hook only when necessary, and remove it as soon as possible.